# Is is possible to manually download app files with Android App Bundles?

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I have an app that uses some data files that the user manually downloads updates every month or so from a server.

Can Android App Bundles replace the downloads from the server? Instead of downloading from a server, will App Bundles allow downloads of app files? Is this free of charge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can split your app in several AppBundle modules. Each module contains an optional feature of your app (e.g. making photos or location tracking). If you are using app bundle you must handle the situation when user tries to use optional feature that wasn't downloaded yet and make him download optional module (for some API's you have to refresh context).

When publishing on Google Play you must now provide bundles instead of single (or several) apks and pass your developer's key to Google Play. Then Google Play compiles an apk for each user individually (set of strings, drawables, optional modules) depending on API version, locality, etc.

I don't think you can update single bundle published on Google Play or check the version of single bundle in your app. So, if you thinking about using Google Play's features to distributing data updates for your app - AFAIK this is not an option. In your case I don't see any difference between updating apk each month and updating bundles each month.